# OpenCV Multilevel B-Spline Approximation

Tags: opencv

Hi (sorry for my english) .. i'm working in a project for University in this project i need to use the MBA (Multilevel B-Spline Approximation) algorithm to get some points (control points) of a image to use in other operations.

I'm reading a lot of papers about this algorithm, and i think i understand, but i can't writing.

The idea is: Read a image, process a image (OpenCV), then get control points of the image, use this points.

So the problem here is:
The algorithm use a set of points {(x,y,z)} , this set of points are approximated with a surface generated with the control points obtained from MBA. the set of points {(x,y,z)} represents de data we need to approximate (the image)..

So, the image is in a cv::Mat format , how can transform this format to an ordinary array to simply access to the data an manipulate...

Here are one paper with an explanation of the method:
(Paper) [REGULARIZED MULTILEVEL B-SPLINE REGISTRATION](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aX8ELTxu7G7UJ%3awww.imt.liu.se/mi_old/Intern/Onlineproceedings/ISBI_2010/pdfs/0000512.pdf+Juan+Pablo+Andrades+Multilevel+B-Spline+Approximation&hl=es&gl=cl&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShfetryzmLOzkBccvVexCmwN-JB17fIs42OhJWLNYqYVzbYR7_aZ7seWBtDnSV0-2JYECePQq9ZQNZs7eqDkYXe9WGhwREReiA3bVLscINlBCqHC3txSg3mhDNBpHRg18ZJObjs&sig=AHIEtbQSbRJcNkuigKIEW8bEj0cAQQ908A)
(Paper)[Scattered Data Interpolation with Multilevel B-splines](http://www.sintef.no/upload/IKT/9011/geometri/MBA/MBA.pdf)
(Matlab)[MBA](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20057)

If someone can help, maybe a guideline, idea or anything will be appreciate ..

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Finally i wrote the algorithm in C++ using armadillo and OpenCV ...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i'm using [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#syntax) a C++ linear algebra library to works with matrix for the algorithm